# Use a user database across multiple projects/servers?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a project, and a sub-project of some kind. Now I want the sub-project to use the same user data for logins as the main project. Essentially I kinda want to use the users table of the main project (and maybe a second table which is related to users aswell). This is not a one-way-road though, I want users to also be able to create accounts on the sub-project, which then again are valid for the main project aswell.

The catch: the projects use different dedicated servers for their SQL databases. (Both MariaDB though, in version 10 or 10.1)

I considered the following options:

1) I could just have 2 mysql instances open in the sub-project, one to access the sub-projects data, and one to access user data from the main project. This comes with the big downside though, that a) well, I have 2 connections open, which likely also comes with performance loss, and b) I can't use any JOINs on the users table at all.

2) I heard about a FEDERATED engine that could be used to automatically make remote calls when a table using FEDERATED engine is involved in some queries. However, it looks like this engine is not supported anymore by MariaDB. (I also didn't come to test it to see what other downsides it may come with. I read somewhere there are potential security concerns with this method, as it is easy to read out the connection information to the master server?)

3) I've never worked with replication, but if I understand this system correctly, I could have a second local database basically be a slave of the users table of the master server, right? However, I fear that this might lead to problems sooner or later, especially if I consider that in future there might be more sub-projects using the main project's users table. Having many servers that sortof maintain exactly the same data sound like a lot of potential troublemakers when several servers try to add (or edit) stuff at the same time.

4) A central login form via OpenID or Oauth is currenly not a desirable option. For now I want each of the projects to provide their own register/login forms.

Which of these (or other) methods would be most optimal, and easy to setup/maintain for this use case?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/setting-up-replication/

Answer (score 0):

While I've voted-to-close this as opinion-based, I'll offer my opinion nonetheless: create a middle service to auth against, and that middle service worries about the details.

The middle service talks to both databases. It first checks database A, then database B. It might cache the results. It might give one database priority over the others. That's the business logic you're hiding behind a convenient REST API you write.

Now, your main project and your sub-project issue REST requests against that now operational middle service. The requests can be dead simple: are these credentials valid? If yes, then establish a session in your project. If session portability is important, use a common library to recognize the session values from each.

This architecture feels the most logical -- parts are separated, business logic is contained in respective units, not too much opportunity for inappropriate redundancy -- but it's veering dangerously close to writing your own auth. You might consider just going ahead and biting the bullet and implementing your middle auth system to use an established protocol (eg OAuth) or to just use an OAuth system outright.